# Make closing question users post a conscious explanation

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions, close-reasons

I have question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14698983/can-a-thread-be-hijacked-otherwise-than-gc-and-some-rare-task-scheduling

I am sure this is valid question - I am not new on SO.

It was closed no comments on the question.

Given that the SO is here for a while - there are lot more users who can close questions (lot more than it was a year ago).

Some users might not even understand the question but have power to close it.

I think to prevent blatant actions - SO should **implement a mandatory comment post if a user votes to close a question**.

Comment: Was the reasn given by the close text under your question unclear in any way? We can help with that; but the feature you're asking for already exists: That's why we have close reasons with supplementary text.

Comment: *As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion. If you feel that this question can be improved and possibly reopened* this is canned response - nobody bothered to read. they just rubber stamp it. in fact - none of the stated applies to my question. What I am saying is that - if you believe the question is wrong you should **consciously** close it not just press a button.

Comment: Beyond any issues with this question, there is an enormous backlog of questions that need to be closed, and new low-quality questions coming in every day. Forcing every user to comment to close would slow the process down tremendously

Comment: OK then.. a blanket justice for everyone... if is that what you believe is right... I have no more questions...

Comment: @BoppityBop What's your reason for believing that nobody who voted to close (or anyone that voted to close) didn't read the question and just blindly pressed the close button?  How do you know that they didn't spend time and effort reviewing it and coming to the decision that it's not a good fit for this site based on guidelines that make this a rather clear case (this not requiring discussing in comments)?  If you, or anyone else, is unsure why a question was closed you can comment on the post or make a meta post asking why it was closed; we will be glad to assist you.

Answer (score 7):

They actually do because whenever a question is closed, some closed text appears explaining why and linking to more information.  It's a default comment left by every closer.